# Where is ADT plugin folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I got a new MacBook Pro and I just installed Eclipse and I followed the install instructions to install the ADT plugin, however after I restart Eclipse I do not know where it downloaded the ADT plugin folder and could not find it, does anyone know where this folder is located?

(it is not located in my user directory/android-sdk)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html.

Answer (score 2):

It is in your eclipse's `plugins` directory, just like any other eclipse plugin.

It's a jar file named `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_xxxx.jar`

Note that the configuration of ADT plugin requires that you enter the location of android SDK in Eclipse's preferences: in Preferences > Android > SDK Location enter the directory where your android SDK was extracted

Comment: Thanks, I did find the jar file and the corresponding directory, but when I open preferences and select this folder Eclipse gives me this error: "Could not find folder 'tools' inside..."

Comment: See my edit: you need to enter the location of the SDK in eclipse's preferences

Comment: I still get the same error when I do that, even after deleting the ADT plugin and reinstalling it and reinstalling Eclipse

Comment: Do you have a 'tools' folder inside your SDK folder?